# V8 Embedding. Cannot print out the `v8::Local` object

Tags: c++, gdb, v8, lldb, embedded-v8

### In Short

I was trying to print out the `v8::Local` object content, with either of `v8/tools/gdbinit` and `v8/tools/lldb_commands.py` helper scripts, I got `Empty Line` OR `Syntax Error` messages. Is there anything I've missed? So my question is **how can we print the `v8::Local` object content?**

---

Most of configurations are from official embed tutorial (https://v8.dev/docs/embed), without any single line of modification. Here are some details:

- *Source Branch*:  "main"    (2022/01/18)
- *GN Build Configuration*:  "x64.release.sample"
- *Program*:  [v8/samples/hello-world.cc](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/samples/hello-world.cc)
- *Platform*:  "Ubuntu18.04 + GDB10" / "macOS 10.14 + LLDB11"

##### GDB ouput:         (ubuntu18.04)

```sh
###  Compile & Link
$ g++ -I. -Iinclude samples/hello-world.cc -o hello_world -lv8_monolith -ldl -Lout.gn/x64.release.sample/obj/ -pthread -std=c++14 -DV8_COMPRESS_POINTERS -g

###  Debug
$ gdb -x tools/gdbinit ./hello_world

(gdb) p result
$1 = {val_ = 0x55d4f7a35408}
(gdb) jlh result
A syntax error in expression, near `)(result).val_))'.
```

##### LLDB ouput:                  (macos10.14)

```sh
###  Compile & Link
$ g++ -I. -Iinclude samples/hello-world.cc -o hello_world -lv8_monolith -Lout.gn/x64.release.sample/obj/ -pthread -std=c++14 -DV8_COMPRESS_POINTERS -g

###  Debug
$ lldb ./hello_world

(lldb) command script import tools/lldb_commands.py
(lldb) b hello-world.cc:56
(lldb) r
(lldb) p *utf8
(char *) $0 = 0x0000000102302590 "Hello, World!"
(lldb) p result
(v8::Local<v8::Value>) $1 = (val_ = 0x0000000102815668)
(lldb) jlh result

(lldb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debugging, try using a debug build: use `gn args <your_output_dir>` to set `is_debug = true`, then recompile.

If you insist on debugging release-mode binaries, you can enable `jlh` and friends with the `v8_enable_object_print = true` GN arg, but your experience will likely be weird in other ways (e.g. stepping and breakpoints won't be reliable, many values will be `<optimized out>`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the effective answer! I tried another branch `*-lkgr`, and along with your suggestion, it works. But I'm still curious about the reason why `jlh` command and friends (including `_v8_internal_Print_Object`)  didn't work in `main` branch, are those Googlers using other ways to print V8 objects content while developing V8 ?_?

Comment: Printing objects works fine with debug builds of the `main` branch. That's the typical developer setup.